# Insert a paragraph from an external HTML page to another HTML page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I'm new to JavaScript so excuse me if what I want to do doesn't make any sense. What I want to do is import a paragraph and a header from an external HTML page to another HTML page, is this possible with JavaScript? If yes can you point me to where I can find the right info.

Page where the imports are going to be done.

```
  <ul>
        <li>
          <h3>Header imported form page 1</h3>
          <p>Paragraph imported from page 1</p>
        </li>

        <li>
          <h3>Header imported form page 2</h3>
          <p>Paragraph imported from page 2</p>
        </li>
  </ul>
```

External Page 1

```
  <h3>Header in page 1</h3>
  <p>Paragraph in page 1</p>
```

External Page 2

```
  <h3>Header in page 2</h3>
  <p>Paragraph in page 2</p>
```

I searched but most of the posts I found are to import complete HTML pages.

FYI - I cannot use PHP since I don't have access to a server.

Thanks

Comment: `"I don't have access to a server."` so how do you plan to host the site?

Comment: This will be hosted locally, this is the documentation for a little program I created which is used by a few engineers within the same company.

Comment: Could you use RSS? Implementation would be a lot easier (there are numerous canned scripts) and it's well supported.

Comment: As an aside, you can run PHP on a local machine via manual configuration or a utility like XAMPP.

Comment: I'm very familiar with MAMP/XAMP but on this case I cannot install additional software in my machine.

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load) method.

> The [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load) method, unlike [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.

For example:

```
 $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
```

> When this method executes, it retrieves the content of ajax/test.html, but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with an ID of container. This element, along with its contents, is inserted into the element with an ID of result, and the rest of the retrieved document is discarded.

Comment: This sounds like a good approach. I will give it a try. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know what I'm missing here but I couldn't make it work. To test I created two pages, in the first one I linked to jQuery, added the code you suggested, pointed the link to my second page and added a paragraph with id of "result". In the second page I added a paragraph with an id of "container" but it didn't work. Have you try this before and works?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds reasonable. From your page, you can use jQuery to send an ajax GET request to the external web page, which should then respond with the full HTML of that page. Use that HTML string to create a jQuery object, and then you can search/parse it with regular jQuery methods,  and pull out the header text, paragraph text, or whatever else you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve that easily with **jquery** using **$.post** or **$.get** method

here is the content of the main page let's call it for example **test.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test </title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="external_page1">
        <!-- here goes the content of the external_page1 -->

    </div>
    <div id="external_page2">
        <!-- here goes the content of the external_page2 -->

    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get('external_page1.html',function(data){ $('#external_page1').html(data);});
        $.get('external_page2.html',function(data){$('#external_page2').html(data);});

        // you can also use $.post method instead of $.get 

        // $.post('external_page1.html',function(data){ $('#external_page1').html(data);});
        // $.post('external_page1.html',function(data){$('#external_page2').html(data);});

    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the content of the two external pages i called them external_page1.html and external_page2.html

so the content of **external_page1.html**(in our case  )

```
<h3>Header in page 1</h3>
<p>Paragraph in page 1</p>
```

and the content of the **external_page2.html**(in our case )

```
<h3>Header in page 2</h3>
<p>Paragraph in page 2</p>
```

**just remember that all the  three files are in the same level**

Comment: I couldn't make it work, I tried both, get and post but no luck. Thanks

Comment: which web browser you are using ?, do you get any kind of error ?